# Abstract class Vs Interface

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

An abstract class is the same thing as an interface except it is an actual class, not just a contract.
Why interface is refered to as a contract ?

Comment: Errr... Because it is a contract...

Comment: That is because, a contract is a thing in which you signed whether you agree or not (you just look to the benefits). In same way, in OOP, a contract (whether you agree or not) is defined by you and you must implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both interface and an abstract class are contracts, since they bind you.

But there other differences between an interface and an abstract class.

Like you said, if you need an actual class, with content to the functions or actual data members with default values, or a ctor, then obviously you will need an abstract class.

But many times, the choose between an interface or an abstract class will be technically the same. And sometimes even in the long term, it will be the same.

Your decision then should be based on the *nature* of what you are looking.

Is it an extra character to your data types? Or does it *define* what your data type **is**?

I've tried to think of any real world example, but I couldn't find any as I haven't done anything with the subject for years now, so I'll give you a book-like example.

Say we have an abstract class Animal:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    abstract string Name;
    abstract bool IsWild;
    abstract bool IsHappy;
}
```

This could have been easily an interface.

And choosing it to be an interface will actually won't have any negative effect on your design.

But in the matter of the nature of it, it must be an abstract class, since `class Dog` **is** an animal. It must be `class Dog : Animal` rather than `class Dog : IAnimal`.

Being an animal is not an extra character of `Dog`. It what **defines** it.

And you want the restrict all the animals to inherit only from `Animal`.

`IAnimal` let someone inherit something else. like:

```
public class Dog : Food, IAnimal {}
```

Interestingly enough, sometimes one might write an abstract class with *nothing at all*, just for the sake of the same thing.

For example, if there was no common property for any `Animal` you will still prefer to do:

```
public abstract class Animal { }

public class Dog : Animal // No actual added value.
{ 
        .........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> An abstract class is the same thing as an interface
>   Not true.  An interface does not define method bodies, private methods, static fields/methods, etc.

Abstract methods can be private ones and therefore are not guaranteed to be accessible to the outside world, interface implementations are obliged to expose the methods of the interface and thus are "guranteeing" the presence and accessibility of such methods, hence the term contract.